# How to add objects in group dynamically in fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

1.I want to add objects dynamically in group, or cloning object dynamically.
2.I have tried  but not working in looping.
3.Want to make group of objects present over canvas (which is dragged by user over canvas)

```
 <script src="js/fabric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" ></canvas>

    <style>
    .canvas {
    border: 1px solid Black;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 1100px;
    }

    </style>

     <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   canvas.setWidth(1100);
  canvas.setHeight(1100);



// clear canvas
  canvas.clear();

  // add red rectangl
  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50, height: 50, left: 50, top: 50, fill: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
}));

  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50, height: 50, left: 110, top: 50, fill: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
  }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50, height: 50, left: 170, top: 50, fill: 'rgb(285,0,0)'
  }));


//var clone = obj.clone();
//alert(obj);

items = canvas._objects;

var group = new fabric.Group([
     // canvas.add(obj)
  canvas.items.clone()
//  canvas.item(1).clone(),
//  canvas.item(2).clone()
]);


canvas.clear().renderAll();
canvas.add(group);




    </script>
```

Comment: try to explain more.. and also post some code.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure but I think you are looking for `addWithUpdate`

Code:

```
group.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Rect({
      ...

    }));
```

for more see this http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3

Comment: yes this works like a charm. group.add() does not work