# Canvas client size in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

In a usual canvas css width and client width could be not equal to each other, how to get this on Fabricjs? As an example: I want 640*360px canvas on a page with 1280*720px image inside.
I know I could scale image, but dataUrl will give me a smaller picture, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [solution](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setDimensions). You could init Fabric.js with CSS sizes and then `setDimensions` with `backstoreOnly` flag or init with desired client size and use `setDimensions` with `cssOnly` flag.
Example #1:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {width: 640, height: 360});
canvas.setDimensions({width: 1280, height: 720}, {backstoreOnly: true});
```

Example #2:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {width: 1280, height: 720});
canvas.setDimensions({width: '640px', height: '360px'}, {cssOnly: true});
```

Comment: can you elaborate more i am facing this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237296/how-to-get-text-object-font-size-after-modifying-object

Comment: When i used below code object is getting blur.
`var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {width: 240px, height: 300px});
canvas.setDimensions({width: '480px', height: '600px'}, {cssOnly: true});`

Comment: @ChiragPatel your canvas grid in this case will be 240*300, but canvas element on the page will be 480*600. First coordinates you set - is drawing coordinates, you cold make line (0;0) -> (240;300) and it will cross whole canvas, no matter which size of real canvas is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the canvas using the `setWidth`/`setHeight` properties of the canvas http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setWidth

e.g.

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setWidth(640);
canvas.setHeight(360);
```

Though you should clarify what you mean.

Comment: This is css size. If you change it, canvas on a page will change size. See that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/IceCreamYou/whL8fu71/

Comment: I don't understand, we're talking about fabricjs, so what's that got to do with default canvas?

Comment: Maybe because I'm asking about this default canvas functionality in fabricjs?

Comment: the default css properties on fabricjs won't work... that's why you have those methods on there.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about css size and client size. I need to save position of an image on the canvas with responsive size (calculated by js when page loaded). `setWidth` and `setHeight` changing both css and client size. 720p image will overflow 640*360 canvas. And like I wrote before, I could set `scale` for image, but 1. Canvas size is responsive, so scale could be different each time and 2. cropped image will be smaller than original not-scaled cropped one.

Comment: Ah, I think I asked a question like that before, maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276877/fabricjs-how-to-detect-total-width-height-of-canvas-where-objects-exist Although you could just grab the left/top, width/height of image, then toDataURL it along with the settings.

Comment: I think I've found a way to do what I've been looking for, check my answer above.