# Can the fontsize be determined from the width and height in fabricJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I am working on a code in fabricJs. I would like to determine the fontsize of a string depending on the width and height of the canvas.
Does anyone have a solution? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237296/how-to-get-text-object-font-size-after-modifying-object/54538071

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're trying to achieve. As it is currently written, your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I would like to know how to add the text to the canvas so that it covers it in its entirety;

Comment: Here is an example in image : 
http://prntscr.com/mkzkaw

Comment: The requirement is to be able to add text dynamically and position it according to the width and height of the canvas.

Comment: Consider checking out https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/